# ngxtranslate to translate popup from Javascript can't work

Tags: javascript, angular, translation, ngx-translate

Onclick my request, the content Are you sure?   is not changing to the required language.

list.component.html

```html
<button type="button" (click)="myrequest(item.Id)">Request View</button>
```

list.component.ts

```js
myrequest((Id: number));
{
  this.notificationService.smartMessageBox(
    {
      title: "Warning",
      content: "{{ 'Are you sure?' | translate }}",
      buttons: "[No][Yes]"
    },
    ButtonPressed => {
      if (ButtonPressed === "Yes") {
        this.loading = true;
        this.FurtherRequest(projectId).subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.loading = false;
          if (data.Success) {
            this.notificationService.successMessage("request submitted");
          } else {
            this.notificationService.errorMessage(data.Message);
          }
        });
      }
      if (ButtonPressed === "No") {
      }
    }
  );
}
```

list.module.ts

```js
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    
imports: [
  TranslateModule],

exports: [
  TranslateModule],
```

Unable to translate things inside js

Comment: you can't do it that way. But you can with subscriber: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740922/how-to-use-ngx-translate-inside-component

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a parameter to translate pipe inside js file.

```
{{  'Are you sure?' | translate :param }}
```

Comment: tried, not working, it print out the full raw line as above

Answer (score 1):

Pipes do not work like this. You need to use `translateService.get` or `translateService.instant` to get a translation programatically.